# Bootstrap 4.1.1 class option for rounded-circle is warped on MVC 5 page when adding padding

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-4

Using VS 2017, bootstrap 4.1.1 for an MVC 5 page I am trying to add right side padding to an image as shown below but when I do the circle of the image is warped.  If I take the padding off the circle is fine but then the text is too close to the circle on the right side:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <br />
    <figure>
      <style>
        .imgRightPadding20 {
          padding-right: 20px;
        }
      </style>
      <img class="img-fluid float-left rounded-circle imgRightPadding20" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="PersonName" />

      <p> Some text about this person. </p>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

The image is a normal square image. I'd like to use the rounded-circle bootstrap feature but the circle gets warped when I add padding to the right side of the image. I need padding because text will flow on the right side of the image. How can I add padding to the right side of the image in a circle without getting the circle warped when using Bootstrap 4.1.1.  Thanks in advance.

========== UPDATE July 5, 2018

For reference, below is what is in the _Layout.cshtml file of my MVC 5 project. If I adopt the proposed  tag changes at the top of the original code then I guess I need to add that to the _Layout.cshtml file? Or are those changes added at the top only for those pages that have the discussed problem? I'm somewhat confused.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - some person Website</title>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body style="padding-top:unset; padding-bottom:unset">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-sm">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Some Person</a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="Index">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                <!--    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>li>-->
            </ul><!-- navbar-nav -->
        </div><!-- container -->
    </nav>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - ASP.NET MVC 5 web application built by some person</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

========== UPDATE July 7, 2018 11:30pm

Here is a picture of the bootstrap Nuget package I installed on my VS 2017 project:

[image]

========= UPDATE July 7, 2018 12:27 a.m.
The only solution I could use was to enclose the img tag with a div tag and apply the float-left and padding to the div tag not the img tag. All the other parts which come with VS 2017 are fine so I do not need the added script statements at the top of the MVC 5 nor the css link line at the top as well.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
      <figure>
         <style>
           .imgRightPadding20 {
           padding-right: 20px;
           }
         </style>

         <div class="float-left imgRightPadding20">
             <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src="~/Content/Images/someperson-200x200.jpg" alt="some person" />
         </div>
         <p>Some text about the person   </p>
      </figure>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could use was to enclose the img tag with a div tag and apply the float-left and padding to the div tag not the img tag. All the other parts which come with VS 2017 are fine so I do not need the added script statements at the top of the MVC 5 nor the css link line at the top as well. The _Layout.cshtml file also remains unchanged. Below is all that was needed:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
      <figure>
         <style>
           .imgRightPadding20 {
           padding-right: 20px;
           }
         </style>

         <div class="float-left imgRightPadding20">
             <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src="~/Content/Images/someperson-200x200.jpg" alt="some person" />
         </div>
         <p>Some text about the person   </p>
      </figure>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `d-flex` class on figure tag, and add margin using `mr-4` class (instead of padding on image).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <br />
      <figure class="d-flex">
        <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle mr-4" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="PersonName" />

        <p> Some text about this person. </p>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**OR**
If you still want to use float , then just change `padding-right: 20px` to `margin-right: 20px;`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <br />
    <figure>
      <style>
        .imgRightPadding20 {
          margin-right: 20px;
        }
      </style>
      <img class="img-fluid float-left rounded-circle imgRightPadding20" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="PersonName" />

      <p> Some text about this person. </p>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code snippets and changes work. I am wondering why your additions work and not the ones provided in Visual Studio 2017 for the _Layout.cshtml file which uses @Styles.Render() and Scripts.Render statements to bring in files like css, modernizr, jquery, and bootstrap. If I adopt your solution I will have to replace what Visual Studio is injecting into the_Layout.cshtml file with what you have provided.  Is that what I am supposed to do going forward with my MVC 5 project?

Comment: I have just included the bootstrap's files using normal script and link tags , not sure how your visual studio is adding them to your project. You should try searching about how to include them in your project with your requirements.

Comment: I used the Manage Nuget Package Tool to add Bootstrap 4.1.1. I have added a picture of the package that is in my project which was added using the VS 2017 Manage Nuget Package Tool found under the VS 2017 menu for Tools->Nuget Package Manager

Comment: Sorry i have literally no idea about the above tool :( Sorry i cant help you with that . :(

Comment: Your code additions work inside the "Run code Snippet" tool. But when I add them to my MVC 5 page the problem still exists. Whether I leave the VS parts in or not the additions don't fix the problem.I"m looking for something that will work in an MVC 5 project under VS 2017. Thank you for your effort though.

Comment: You are welcome :) Let me know if it gets solved for you afterwards :)